# How to splice plots seamlessly in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have three sets of data to plot as follows:

```
set1=[1.2, 4.5, 3.2, 2.4, 6.3, 2.3, 5.4, 5.7, 4.3, 3.3, 1.1]
set2=[1.6, 4.5, 3.2, 2.4, 9.3, 7.3, 5.4, 5.7, 4.1, 3.3, 1.1]
set3=[1.2, 5.5, 3.2, 2.4, 2.3, 2.3, 5.4, 5.7, 7.3, 3.3, 0.1]
```

I can plot each one of them alone like this

```
plot(0:0.1:1, set1)
```

However, now I wish to splice them one next to another, following the order `set1`, `set2`, and finally `set3`. Note that I am **NOT looking for subplot**. Instead, I am trying to **splice** them one next to another **seamlessly**.

How may I do that?

Comment: `plot([set1 set2 set3])` ?

Comment: @LuisMendo, I guess rather `plot(0:0.1:1, [set1' set2' set3'])`...

Comment: @A.Donda But the OP says "splice them"... I understand that as attaching one after the other

Comment: @LuisMendo: true, but considering that he is giving x-values to be used for plotting... Who knows, clearly a case of "unclear what you're asking". ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can plot each of the segments alone, and are only worried about drawing the line, simply use `hold on`;

```
hold on
plot(0:0.1:1, set1)
plot(1:0.1:2, set2) %I took a guess at these x coordinates
plot(2:0.1:3, set3)
```

You can also combine them as Luis recommended , but in this way you don't need to worry about overlapping areas looking strange or about the order of the sets.

If you want different colors for the lines, use `hold all` instead.